# PCB copper edge for delivering power

Tags: power, pcb, power-electronics, pcb-fabrication, pcb-layers

I want to tell a PCB manufacturer to create copper edges for the PCB that should pass power from USB Type-C connector that is connected to USB PD charger:

[image]

This power module will be soldered to another platform PCB that has these holes with their corresponding pads:
[image]

Is there any recommended copper that should be used in this case? Any considerations that I need to take? And what is the correct terminology for this kind of PCB edge feature that I should use?

**Update**: Regarding the answer of Mattman944, is using tin/lead finish means that we should have edges like these but have a tin-lead solder on top of copper? Which means we will have copper edge but plated with tin-lead (gray color)?

Also, why exposing copper is not wanted in this case?
[image]

Comment: It appears that you have made an "edge" connector. The copper will corrode, so it must be plated with a non-corroding metal, often gold. The thin layer of plating means that this should not be used for applications where this will be inserted many times.

Comment: The card will be soldered to the motherboard just one time and will not be disconnected. maybe we can use cheaper copper plating than gold in this case? and If yes, which one?

Comment: If you are going to solder it, you still don't want exposed copper, but you can use the normal tin/lead finish (or whatever they use in lead free boards now).

Comment: I hope I understood you right. I added an update to illustrate my understanding, hope you can take a look.

Comment: This may be a complex and high cost way to obtain a vertical USB mount. Is it important that the mounting be exactly 90 degrees? You will likely face a number of alignment issues depending on the finished size of the holes and square pins. A loose fit will simplify assembly but may result in the part being off of 90 degree. A tight fit may ensure a 90 degree mount but could be difficult to assemble. An alternative may be to use a USB connector designed with a 90 degree mounting position. They are not common but here are a few from Molex: https://www.molex.com/pdm_docs/sd/2169890001_sd.pdf

Comment: Hi, @Nedd this board has other IC's to perform negotiations with USB-PD charger to get a fixed 20V output. it's not an alternative for vertical USB Type-C connector.

Comment: @Firas - OK.  If there is no extra space on the main board or this addition makes the system more configurable then that gives some rationale for considering an add-on board. Though I still believe my comment about being complex and costly stands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edge plating can be specified, yes.  Usually by making a plated feature like a slot pad, using a few overlapping ones to get the odd geometry; and then cut up with more overlapping board slots (cutouts, edges, or unplated slot holes).  The board fab may have some comments about design intent with respect to the overlapping features.  Sending a rendering isn't a bad idea.

The motherboard obviously benefits from having side metallization, which can be produced by using plated pads with slot shaped holes, as above.

The side metallization on the daughterboard adds little, I think; using just the facing pads (no side metallization) is standard.

But using right-angle headers is even more standard, I would say.

As for plating, whatever fits in the slot, and is solderable, will do.  If assembly will be soon after delivery, OSP can be used; otherwise, a longer lasting plating such as HASL, ENIG or tin should be chosen.

HASL would be the least attractive of these options, having more surface roughness (height) than the other finishes.  This will not affect assembly however, as the rout tolerances dominate (typically approx. ±0.13mm).  That is, you must make the rout oversized enough to ensure fitment between max. daughterboard and min. motherboard connector dimensions.